# clear form values submitting through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here my form is getting cleared through ajax and  i had validation for all the fields and the problem am facing here is  when i enter data for one field and submitting the form the value entered in that field is getting disappeared i want that to be remain.
Here is my ajax please have a look

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#send').click(function() {

var form_data = {
  name: $('#name').val(),
  email: $('#email').val(),
  message: $('#message').val()

};
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/contact_form",
  type: 'POST',
  data: form_data,
  success: function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'YES')
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
    else if (msg == 'NO')
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>');
    else
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');

  }


});


$( '#contact' ).each(function(){
this.reset();
});


return false;


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trigger` to reset your form after success event. You are resetting form outside of ajax so on every call it will reset. Try below code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#send').click(function() {

var form_data = {
  name: $('#name').val(),
  email: $('#email').val(),
  message: $('#message').val()

};
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/contact_form",
  type: 'POST',
  data: form_data,
  success: function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'YES')
    {
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
        $( '#contact' ).trigger("reset");
     }
    else if (msg == 'NO')
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>');
    else
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');

  }


});


return false;


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that in the ajax's success callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#send').click(function() {
      var form_data = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        message: $('#message').val()
      };
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/contact_form",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
          if (msg == 'YES')
            $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
            $('#contact')[0].reset(); // <------here you can reset it.
          else if (msg == 'NO')
            $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>');
          else
            $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');

        }
      });
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

---

Also this is not a valid way to have multiple IDs as per this code:

```
$( '#contact' ).each(function(){
   this.reset();
});
```

If you don't have it then just use as i have marked in the success.

Comment: i had changed as per what you have told but when i submit the button the page is redirecting without showing any validation rule

Comment: You forgot to add `{` after if in success event

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$('#Your_form_id').trigger('reset');
```

Answer (score 0):

First place your code in a document ready statement, second you need to put the reset in the success function of the ajax call so the form clears after the data is added to the db

```
$(function(){
$('#send').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var form_data = {
  name: $('#name').val(),
  email: $('#email').val(),
  message: $('#message').val()

};
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/contact_form",
  type: 'POST',
  data: form_data,
  success: function(msg) {
     //do reset here after success
    if (msg == 'YES') {
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');}
    else if (msg == 'NO') {
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>');
    } else {
      $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');

  }}


});
});
```

Note you should use classes instead of ids if you have multiple looped forms